# Objective C: How to Use the kCGBlendModeHue and kCGBlendModeSaturation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

i tried using the CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor before now i want to use other way to do the color change.

I am using now an image as a stroke and i want to change it's color with the use of those CGBlendModes.

How will i able to control the Hue and Saturation using kCGBlendModeHue and kCGBlendModeSaturation? i'll use it to change the stroke color on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to do something like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image.CGImage);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, overlay.CGImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Patrick Tescher's answer, this works:

```
- (void) changeToHue:(float)hue saturation:(float)saturation {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    UIView *hueBlend = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    hueBlend.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:1 alpha:1];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, self.image.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
    [hueBlend.layer renderInContext:context];
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
```